# If my webpage has multiple internal links, will that affect my website's SEO?

Tags: seo, links, keywords

So my website is a programming tutorial site, and some of my pages have multiple internal links using `<a href=" ">`.

In my website, a list of programs will be show like this:

- program to print from 0 to n using for loop
- program to print from 0 to n using while loop
- program to print from 0 to n using do while loop
- program to print n natural numbers and their sum

All of the links start with the same keywords. Will this affect the SEO of my website?

Answer (score 1):

Too much of anything is considered bad; now what we call too much is the question here. In your case, you have very few links and that's absolutely fine and shouldn't cause any problems with using similar keywords for interlinking from an SEO point-of-view.

You can read more about this [here](https://moz.com/community/q/too-much-internal-linking).

Answer (score 1):

All content and links will affect the SEO of your site.

I would say in this case it would be a positive effect. You're causing an association between your pages via the links and their text. The association seems valid and helps search engines determine what pages are about and related to. Each linked page is about C programming, so that association is good.

Also think about what is best for your users. Your link structure seems logical and should provide a good user experience.